# Microsoft Word Document Current Path

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have created an Excel to Word mailmerge and the Word document is my Merge Template.

When i use the current path codes, e.g. CurDir(), ActiveDocument.Path,ThisDocument.FullName etc. etc. it gives me:

`C:\users\rgillooly\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates` 
Which is where the Normal.dotm file sits.

Is there any code that will pick up the "Files" actual location and not where its pointing to ?
`E.g. C:\users\rgillooly\desktop\MailMerge`

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saved my document **master.docm** (Word Document with Macros):
It gives the directory of the good current document:

```
CurDir() => C:\users\rgillooly\desktop\MailMerge
ActiveDocument.Path => C:\users\rgillooly\desktop\MailMerge
ThisDocument.FullName => C:\users\rgillooly\desktop\MailMerge\master.docm
```

If saved as **master.dotm** (Word Template), it gives config directory:

```
CurDir() => C:\users\rgillooly\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
ActiveDocument.Path =>
ThisDocument.FullName => C:\users\rgillooly\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\master.dotm
```